# Regex Pattern required in java for matching string starts with '{{' and ends with "}}"

Tags: java, regex

> Hi,
>       I need to create a regex pattern that will pick the matching string starts with '{{' and ends with 
>   "}}" from a given string.
>
> ```
> The pattern I have created is working same with the strings starting with '{{{' and '{{', Similarly with ending with '}}}' and
> ```
>
> '}}'
>
> ```
> Output of above code:
> matches = {{phone2}}
> matches = {{phone3}}
> matches = {{phone5}}
>
>
> **Expected Output**:
> matches = {{phone5}}
>
> I need only Strings which follows two consecutive pattern of '{' and '}' not three.
> ```

Sharing the code below

```
    package com.test;

    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "<test>{{#phone1}}<a href=\"tel:{{{phone2}}}\">{{{phone3}}}</a>{{/phone4}} {{phone5}}></test>";

        //String pattern = "\\{\\{\\s*?(\\w*?)\\s*?(?!.*\\}\\}\\}$)";
        String pattern = "\\{\\{\\s*?(\\w*?)\\s*?}}";
            Pattern placeholderPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher placeholderMatcher = placeholderPattern.matcher(text);
            while (placeholderMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("matches = " + placeholderMatcher.group());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: **Expected Output **:
matches = {{phone5}}

Comment: no it's  having issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\{)\\{{2}\\s*(\\w*)\\s*\\}{2}(?!\\})";
```

Or, if empty or blank `{{...}}` are not expected, use

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\{)\\{{2}\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\}{2}(?!\\})";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iXeHvx/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\{)` -  a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a `{` char immediately to the left of the current location
- `\{{2}` - `{{` substring
- `\s*` - 0+  whitespaces
- `(\w*)` - Group 1: one or more word chars (1 or more if `+` quantifier is used)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\}{2}` - `}}` string
- `(?!\})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `}` char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/XbCMkG):

```
String text = "<test>{{#phone1}}<a href=\"tel:{{{phone2}}}\">{{{phone3}}}</a>{{/phone4}} {{phone5}}></test>";
String pattern = "(?<!\\{)\\{{2}\\s*(\\w*)\\s*\\}{2}(?!\\})";
Pattern placeholderPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher placeholderMatcher = placeholderPattern.matcher(text);
while (placeholderMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match: " + placeholderMatcher.group());
    System.out.println("Group 1: " + placeholderMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
Match: {{phone5}}
Group 1: phone5
```

Comment: Thank you very much, String pattern = "(?<!\\{)\\{{2}\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\}{2}(?!\\})"; It worked fine for my problem

Comment: Done. Thank you once more.